# Check if an Action exists in Kohana

Tags: kohana

I am writing an error handler for Kohana. There is a controller `Controller_Errors` (which inherits `Controller_Kohana_Errors`) with actions like `action_404`, `action_403`, `action_500`, etc.

**Route:**

```
Route::set('errors','errors/<action>', array (
        'action' => '[\d]{3}',
    ))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'errors',
    ));
```

**included sample bootstrap.php**

```
try {
    $response = Request::factory()->execute();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // If we are in development and the error wasn't a 404, show the stack trace.
    // Otherwise, show a nice error.
    if ((Kohana::$environment == KOHANA::DEVELOPMENT) AND ( ! ($e->getCode() == 404 OR $e->getCode() == 403))) {
        throw $e;
    }
    // Log the error
    Kohana::$log->add(Log::ERROR, Kohana_Exception::text($e));

    $error_code = 500;
    if ($e instanceof ReflectionException) {
        $error_code = 404;
    }
    if ($e instanceof HTTP_Exception)
    {
        $error_code = $e->getCode();
    }
    $request = Request::factory('errors/'.$error_code);
    if (*__NOT SURE WHAT GOES HERE__*) {
        $request = Request::factory('errors/500');
    }
    $response = $request->execute();
}

// Send the headers and echo the response
echo $response->send_headers()->body();
```

I would like to allow people to extend my class, so I need some way to check if an action exists, and if not, change to show a 500 error. (See the line that says `*__NOT SURE WHAT GOES HERE__*`.)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the following code will do it:

```php
if ($request->status == 404 && $error_code != 404) ...
```

In this case, you know that the 404 did not come from the original request, and therefore must have come from the attmpt to load an error page for the error code.

Comment: That would require it to be inside ANOTHER try/catch that executes the request. That does not seem like the most efficient way.

Comment: Why would it have to be inside another try/catch?  Which part of this is throwing another exception?

Comment: `$request = Request::factory('errors/'.$error_code);` does not set the status. You need to call `execute()` first, and then it throws an exception.